Debug multiple node services via docker compose in VS Code
I'm trying to debug multiple Node.js services using Docker Compose, but I'm encountering issues with port conflicts. I have configured different ports for each service, yet I receive the following error for worker service
I am able to attach the debugger for the collector service successfully and hit breakpoints. However, for the worker service, although the debugger attaches, the breakpoints do not hit, and I get the "address already in use" error.
What am I doing wrong? How can I properly debug both services simultaneously using Docker Compose?
docker ps                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                                 COMMAND                  CREATED         STATUS                   PORTS                                                                                                                                                                                                     NAMES
f49b96d90d91   workers     "docker-entrypoint.s…"   7 minutes ago   Up 7 minutes             0.0.0.0:9250->9250/tcp, :::9250->9250/tcp                                                                                                                                                                 
92565587fb86   collector   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   7 minutes ago   Up 7 minutes             0.0.0.0:3000->3000/tcp, :::3000->3000/tcp, 0.0.0.0:9229->9229/tcp, :::9229->9229/tcp


docker logs -f f49b96d90d91
Debugger listening on ws://0.0.0.0:9250/1410e992-182c-4b92-8cb3-0d0c642157bf
For help, see: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector
Starting inspector on 0.0.0.0:9250 failed: address already in use
...
Debugger attached.

Here is launch.json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "attach",
            "name": "Debug: Collector",
            "remoteRoot": "/app/collector",
            "localRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/collector",
            "port": 9229,
            "restart": true,
            "sourceMaps": true,
            "resolveSourceMapLocations": ["${workspaceFolder}/**", "!**/node_modules/**"],
            "trace": true
        },
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "attach",
            "name": "Debug: Worker",
            "remoteRoot": "/app/workers",
            "localRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/workers",
            "port": 9250,
            "restart": true,
            "sourceMaps": true,
            "resolveSourceMapLocations": ["${workspaceFolder}/**", "!**/node_modules/**"],
            "trace": true
        },
    ]
}

Here's a snippet of my docker-compose.yml:
  collector:
    build:
      context: .
      target: collector
    environment:
      ....
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
      - 9229:9229 # Debug port
    volumes:
      - ./tsconfig.json:/app/tsconfig.json
      - ./collector:/app/collector
      - ./shared:/app/shared
    command: [
      "npx", 
      "nodemon", 
      "--signal", "SIGINT", 
      "--nolazy",
      "--watch", "collector/**/*.ts", 
      "--watch", "shared/**/*.ts", 
      "--ext", "ts",
      "--exec", "node --inspect=0.0.0.0:9229 -r ts-node/register",         
      "collector/server.ts", 
    ]

  workers:
    build:
      context: .
      target: workers
    environment:
     ....
    ports:
      - 9250:9250 # Debug port
    volumes:
      - ./workers:/app/workers
      - ./shared:/app/shared
      - ./tsconfig.json:/app/tsconfig.json
    command: [
      "npx", 
      "nodemon",
      "--signal", "SIGINT", 
      "--nolazy",
      "--watch", "workers/**/*.ts", 
      "--watch", "shared/**/*.ts", 
      "--ext", "ts", 
      "--exec", "node --inspect=0.0.0.0:9250 -r ts-node/register",    
      "workers/master.ts"
    ]

Directory structure
├── api
│   ├── queries
│   └── routes
├── collector
│   ├── modules
│   ├── queries
│   └── routes
├── shared
│   ├── lib
│   ├── queries
│   └── routes
└── workers
    └── stream

